Are all Turkish Airlines covered by rules similar to the EC261?
All flights departing the European Union are covered, this question is about other flights from Turkish Airlines.
On this page I found information that reminds me a bit of the EC261. However, the compensation amounts are not specified. I wander what is the actual compensation, is it analogous to the EC 261?

The Turkish regulation (SHY-passenger) is essentially a copy-paste of EC261. It provides the same amount of compensation as specified in EC261, except that the amount is converted to Turkish lira (article 8).

When referred to this article, a compensation of Turkish Lira
equivalent of 100 Euros shall be paid to passengers for domestic
flights. For international flights, the passengers shall be given;
a)
a compensation of the Turkish Lira equivalent of 250 Euros for all the
flights of 1500 kilometers or shorter,
b) a compensation of the
Turkish Lira equivalent of 400 Euros for all the flights between 1500
and 3500 kilometers,
c) a compensation of the Turkish Lira equivalent
of 600 Euros for all the flights longer than 3500 kilometers

It is worth mentioning however even if the regulations are the same or very similar, each jurisdiction can interpret them differently. For example, the right to compensation for excessive delays (instead of outright cancellations) results from the interpretation of the European regulation by the ECJ (the supreme court for EU Community law). This interpretation is not binding in countries outside EU/EEA* even if a parallel or similar regulation is adopted.
* I specifically choose to use the term EU/EEA here to exclude Switzerland. ECJ decisions on civil aviation are not automatically binding in Switzerland even if the exact text of EC261 is law in Switzerland.

Thanks, that's exactly the info I was looking for.

This document , published by the Turkish Civil Aviation Authority (Sivil Havacılık Genel Müdürlüğü) , mentions all the prices in euros but the Turkish arline would pay the equivalent amount in Turkish lira.

I've had Pegasus pay me in EUR for a denied boarding Turkey-Italy

The currency seems to depend on the country where the money is requested. I got compensated for a denied boarding on a Turkey-Canada flight in Canada and got it in canadian dollars.
